# Static variables initialized with returned value by a static function?

Tags: actionscript-3

When I initialize a static const variable with the string returned by a static function, it is wrong, and the value of the static const variable is "".
The code is as follow:

```
public static const BALL_TIP:String = Lang.getInstance.parse(LangConst.BALL_TIP);
```

I think the possible reason is that the static variable is initialized in the phase that function is can't be called.

please help me know why it is. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: you can't run code at that scope.

Comment: Could you explain it clearly , or give me some document ？

Comment: Yeah, i'm also not sure if you can do that for constants. but declaring it as "public static var" could work ?

Comment: static variables are initialized before classes are loaded in the app. As a result class instances are always created after static variables. Your code attempts to initialize a static variable using an instance of a class value which correctly returns nothing since the instance can't exist at that point.

Comment: Debug and see what argument `parse` is receiving with this call. Also, does `Lang` have a language set when this code is called? Probably not, perhaps your translation code returns `""` because it doesn't know what language to translate it to. Do anything fancy in static scope is asking for trouble, I would just translate the `BALL_TIP` value when you need to display it.